# How to make the root url of angular service class at one configurable location

Tags: angular

In Angular service class I have defined the root url of the web api as below

```
readonly rootURL:string = "https://abc.xyz.com" ;
```

I have this now in all my service classes to make the GET\POST... request to my webapi.

**My Problem**

So if I have to change my webapi url I need to change the rootURL defined in all service classes.

**My Requirement**

How to keep the rootURL at one location and if possible as a configurable one even after deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the ways you can do it is by creating a globals.ts file and adding your variables in it like:

```
// globals.ts
'use strict';

export const rootURL='abc.com';
```

And then in your services you can import and use the variable like:

```
import { rootURL } from './globals'
```

Comment: Yes this works for me. I have used this as my app is to be delivered ASAP. But is it possible to make it configurable after deployment. Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We can create proxy config settings, and we can change the targeted url there.

> proxy.config.json

```
 {
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:4200/",
    "secure": false
  },
  "/user-api": {
    "target": "http://your-targeted-url.com",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true

  }
}
```

> UserService.ts

```
 @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

 getUser():  Observable<User> {
     return this.http.get<any>(/user-api/project/user) // we are not 
                                                 passing base url here, we only change the base targeted url in the proxy-config.json
    .pipe(map(data => {
      return data.body;
    }));
  }



getAllUsers():  Observable<User[]> {
         return this.http.get<any>(/user-api/project/users) // no base 
                                                             url
        .pipe(map(data => {
          return data.body;
        }));
      }
```

}

Comment: I am new to angular.Can you please elaborate on the steps to make it, 1. like where should the json file be added ; 2. Will just referring `/user-api/project/user` will take the url from json file? ...Thanks in advance.